# Power BI custom connectors for manipulating data from API endpoints

Tags: powerbi, m

I am creating a custom connectors for manipulating data from API endpoints by passing necessary parameters to an endpoint. As one of my requirement is to pass array of strings/list of strings as a required parameter to the API. For example, [list of string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2v3k.jpg).

Then after selecting the required parameter the endpoint would look like -

```
curl --request GET \

--url 'https://api.example.com/fleet/vehicles/stats/history?types=auxInput6,auxInput13' \

--header 'accept: application/json'
```

So how do I write this in m language so users can select list in Power BI and for selected options API will call that parameter and present the output data.

I tried list function but that doesn't work.